# Why do coloured water droplets form rings upon drying up?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, everyday-life, evaporation

While cleaning my fountain pen, I spilled some water on the table. The water drops had some ink dissolved in them. When these drops dried up, the deposited pigment density was visibly much higher near the edge of the drop, than at the bulk. Why does this happen?

[image]

Comment: This is an example of the ["Coffee Ring Effect"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coffee_ring_effect). [Here is a non-paywalled version](https://jfi.uchicago.edu/~tten/Coffee.drops/Nagel.7.4.pdf) of the classic Nature paper on ["Capillary flow as the cause of ring stains from dried liquid drops"](https://doi.org/10.1038/39827 "Deegan, R., Bakajin, O., Dupont, T. et al. Nature 389, 827–829 (1997)").

Answer (score 8, accepted):

as the droplet evaporates, the dissolved stuff becomes progressively more concentrated because it doesn't evaporate. in addition, if the fluid wets the surface it is sitting on, the boundary of the droplet is "pinned" in place so the droplet coverage area stays the same as the droplet progressively thins down.

Now consider that the evaporation rate depends locally on how much surface area is present relative to the nearby internal volume. A parcel of fluid at the boundary line can evaporate "sideways" as well as "up" and so the evaporation rate there is greater than for the middle of the droplet where there are no "sides".

This concentrates the exsolved solids at the boundary, forming a visible ring at the boundary.

Comment: Cool! So in the end, the evaporation would probably cause a 2D radial flow directed towards the edges?

Comment: @AlphaLife, yup yup!

Comment: This is a beautiful answer and honestly deserves more attention.

Comment: @matt hanson, thank you for your kind words. -NN

Answer (score 8):

It may be important that ink is colloidal. See  [Annual Review of Chemical and Biomolecular Engineering  Volume 14, 2023  Thampi, pp 53-83](https://www.annualreviews.org/doi/full/10.1146/annurev-chembioeng-101121-085056)

@niels nielsen emphasized the importance of pinning of the boundary. According to the reference above,

> These studies also put forward the conditions under which edge or
> peripheral deposits typically form. First, the continuous medium in
> which the particles are dispersed must evaporate. Second, when placed
> on a solid substrate, the drop should have a nonzero contact angle.
> Third, the contact line of the drop must be pinned to the initial
> position during the course of drying. During the evaporation of
> solvent from drying drops, the contact line on the substrate may move;
> however, this movement may not always be smooth. Since no substrates
> are atomically smooth, their surfaces will always possess physical and
> chemical heterogeneities. Such heterogeneities can inhibit the local
> motion of the contact line, resulting in pinning of the contact line
> on the substrate. Depending on the strength of pinning, two different
> modes of evaporation may be observed. The first is the constant
> contact radius (CCR) mode, in which the contact line remains pinned
> during the observation window. Correspondingly, the contact angle
> systematically decreases (Figure 2a). The second is the constant
> contact angle (CCA) mode, in which the contact line is not pinned.
> Instead, the contact line continuously recedes, and the contact angle
> remains constant throughout the observation window (Figure 2b).
> Surface tension forces maintain the equilibrium contact angle, θ,
> during this process. In general, most of the experiments show that
> particle-laden drops evaporate via a combination of CCA and CCR modes.
> The drying of drops in CCR mode is a prerequisite for the formation of
> ring-shaped deposits. The outward flow of solvent (see Section 4) that
> carries the particles from the drop interior to the edge, as imaged by
> time-resolved microscopy, conclusively proves that ring deposits form
> as a consequence of the flows generated due to loss of liquid from
> drops evaporating on solid substrates. In addition, the mass of
> particles in the ring increases with time in a power-law fashion,
> regardless of the type of particle, dispersion medium, or substrate
> wettability.

They also write:

> Water, a natural substance used in all applications, often contains
> salt and other dissolved materials. When drops of salt solution (43,
> 84, 85), sucrose, glucose, fructose (44), and so forth are dried, the
> higher evaporative flux will cause supersaturation to occur near the
> contact line and the first crystals will form near the contact line.
> Nucleation may occur at the liquid–air interface or at the
> solid–liquid interface in the vicinity of the contact line. The newly
> formed crystals can remain anchored or be pushed inward by the
> dynamics of the interface (86). Thus, the final patterns obtained
> depend on the location of the nucleation site, the growth dynamics,
> and the fluid dynamics in the evaporating drop.
>
> Unlike particles, crystallized salt near the contact line is generally
> less capable of pinning the contact line (43, 44). Therefore, drop
> evaporation may proceed with either continuous or discontinuous
> depinning of the contact line, causing the radial convection in the
> drop to weaken. Thus, a uniform deposit or concentric rings may be
> obtained instead of a coffee ring. On the other hand, a coffee-ring
> pattern can be obtained through the addition of colloidal particles to
> the solutions, which will pin the contact line (43).

Overall, the phenomenon is quite complex. You may wish to look at the reference.